# How to install a2dissite and a2ensite on openSUSE 11.3?

Tags: software-installation, opensuse, yast

I don't have the a2dissite and a2ensite commands on my openSUSE 11.3 webserver.
How can I add them?
I didn't find these commands with YAST. Maybe, because there are no openSUSE 11.3 repositories anymore?
How can I install/ make available a2dissite and a2ensite?

Answer (score 1):

Those commands are usually only avaliable in Debian based systems. You must symlink manually in Suse as far as I've read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, sorry, I don't understand the relation to my question. I am wondering how to install some Apache-related tools and not how to start Apache.

Comment: @KB those "tools" are in fact scripts run by apache installed on the default apache package. But in SuSe they have a different name rcapache2 and another tool the "server wizard" which is on the link I provided you. With those I believe you can fix your issue.

Comment: @vfbsilva: a2ensite/a2dissite are used to enable/disable sites (virtual hosts) running under apache. It has nothing to do with start/stop apache itself...

Comment: @VajkHermecz thanks for pointing it out. I did find a better explanation in one of the stack exchange sites I will paste the link here for reference. http://serverfault.com/questions/548212/how-to-a2ensite-and-a2dissite

Would you like to edit my answer to have the proper credits? Regards,